# A patch that doesn't contain line numbers, is it possible?

Tags: diff, patch

I would add two lines of text to a file if they don't exist there yet. The lines can be in various positions in that file. So a regular patch will rather not work. Can there be a simplified patch, that only contains lines to add:

```
> Line 1
> Line 2
```

? This doesn't feel like a regular patch anymore. I guess I will need software other than `patch`?

Comment: You could use `sed`

Comment: You could just `grep` for the two lines and if they do not exist you just can add them to the end (eg using `echo "line 1" >> file_to_patch`) - if the position does not matter.

Comment: Is the order of lines in the file totally irrelevant, or do you mean that the lines to look for are not in a fixed position, but the order of lines otherwise matters?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how patches work. The `patch` utility applies a patch created by the `diff` utility run on two existing versions of a file or set of files.  The two versions are static, and applying the patch will transform one into the other (both directions are possible).

To just append the lines of a file (`lines.in`) that are completely missing in another file (`file.dat`), you may use `comm` like this (`bash` and `ksh93`):

```
comm -23 <( sort lines.in ) <( sort file.dat ) >>file.dat
```

The added lines will be sorted.

A solution that preserves the ordering of the lines in `lines.in`:

```
grep -v -x -F -f file.dat lines.in >>file.dat
```

This will use `grep` to find all lines in `lines.in` that does not (`-v`) exist in `file.dat` (`-f file.dat`) and append them to `file.dat`.  The complete lines are compared as fixed strings (`-x -F`).

Comment: Äh, right, my bad.

Comment: @ilkkachu No worries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes up when updating configuration files.  For example, you can do this as shell script functions:

```
#!/bin/sh
add_data() {
    grep "^$2$" "$1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo "$2" >>"$1"
}

add_data program.conf "Line 1"
add_data program.conf "Line 2"
```

In this example, I've anchored the expression so that only lines which have no extra text will match.  But it assumes there are no meta characters in the data.  This call would not add its literal text:

```
add_data program.conf ".*Line 2$"
```

You could work around that by escaping the characters which are likely to cause a problem with grep.

Commenters point out that one can work around *that* problem using the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) option **`-x`**:

> Consider only input lines that use all characters in the line excluding the terminating  to match an entire fixed string or regular expression to be matching lines.

with this result:

```
#!/bin/sh
add_data() {
    grep -F -x "$2" "$1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo "$2" >>"$1"
}

add_data program.conf "Line 1"
add_data program.conf "Line 2"
add_data program.conf ".*Line 2$"
```

Comment: `fgrep -x` (fixed strings, match whole line) might be useful here

Comment: @ilkkachu `grep -x -F` to even make it POSIX. Thanks for spotting that `-x` flag! I was actually not aware of it. Much goodliness.

Answer (score 0):

If you put just those lines to add in a file like:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

You could do:

```
pcregrep -xqM "\Q$(cat that-file)\E" file-to-patch ||
  cat that-file >> file-to-path
```

That's assuming `that-file` doesn't contain `\E` and doesn't end in empty lines.